# Is there a way to see which list item was found when using the any function in python?

Tags: python, list, any

I have a list of of words which I want to find in a text file.
Right now I'm trying the `any` method to iterate through lines in a file.
It returns `True` or `False` correctly so it's working fine.

My question though is if it's possible to see which word it found?
I can see with my code and the text which word was found but I would like to use it in the code somehow if it's possible.

An example of what I mean below. This code returns `True` or `False` if any of the words are in the `line`.

```py
list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon']

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    x = any(word in line for word in list_of_words)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `next` instead, with a `default` in case no element is found.

```
x = next((word for word in list_of_words if word in line), None)
if x is not None:
    ...
```

If `None` can be an element in the list, you may use some dedicated sentinel object instead, e.g.

```
not_in = object()
x = next((word for word in list_of_words if word in line), not_in)
if x is not not_in:
    ...
```

Or explicitly catch the `StopIteration` error:

```
try:
    x = next(word for word in list_of_words if word in line)
    ...
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Note that *all* of these approaches only give you the *first* such element, and then stop checking the rest (like `any` does); if instead you are interested in *all* such elements, you should use a list comprehension as in the other answer.

Comment: For now I just want to now the first word found so this works great, thank you.
I will explore the `next` function some more since I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `any`, use a simple list comprehension as follows:

```
    x = [word for word in list_of_words if word in line]
```

This will return a list of the words in that line

Comment: This is also a valid solution. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally,you want to use a `set` instead of a list to hold the important words.
If you just want to know which words were found and don't care how many times they are found, then this will work:

```py
words = set(['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'])

with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    words_in_line = set(line.split()) # or however else you want to put them in a set.
    for word in words_in_line.intersection(words):
        print(word)
```

Borrowing a bit from another comment, an even better way to solve it is this:

```py
words = set(['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'])

with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    words_in_line = (word for word in line.split() if word in words)
    for word in words_in_line:
        print(word)
```

This makes use of the fact that a generator object, i.e. the object created by iterating over the words in the line is also an iterable, and thus, if it is empty the iteration will stop immediately, and if any elements exist, it will iterate over them.

Comment: I tried your second example but it does not print anything even though the word is in the line. 

I tried `print(words_in_line)` and it says generetor object, but I can't iterate through it.

Comment: Your first example workes great though. With enumerate I can see which word was found on which line.

Comment: Try using `.split`, see the correction I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assignment operator `:=`:

```py
list_of_words = ["apple", "banana", "lemon"]

sample_lines = [
    "this is line 1",
    "this line 2 has banana in it.",
    "this is line 3",
]

for line in sample_lines:
    if any((found_word := word) in line for word in list_of_words):
        print(found_word)
```

Prints:

```
banana
```